# Помогите передать в один универсальный метод для записи данных в БД разные списки List (модели данных)

Tags: java

Проблема в следующем. Допустим есть две разные модели данных Table1 и Table2
Я получаю данные с страницы JSP в сервлет и заполняю эти модели в массив records который
имеет тип одной из этих моделей.После этого я хочу получить массив в методе добавления в БД 
model.insert(records)

Вопрос в том как в методе insert обратиться к соответствующим геттерам моделей?
Если я не понимаю что пришло в метод Table1 или Table2??
Метод хочется универсальный. Помогите пожалуйста, желательно с примером.

метод

```
insert
Table1 или Table1  element;
for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
element = (Table1 или Table2) records.get(i);
String name = element.getName();
int vid = element.getId();
}


case "Tab1":
Table1 table1 = null;
records = new ArrayList<Table1>();
table1 = new Table1(
Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")),
formatter.parse(request.getParameter("datan")),// тип date
request.getParameter("name").trim(),
records.add(table1);

case "Tab2":
Table2 table2 = null;
records = new ArrayList<Table2>();
table2 = new Table2(
Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")),
request.getParameter("pole").trim(),
request.getParameter("name").trim(),
records.add(table2);


model.insert(records);


public class Table1 {
private int id;
private Date Data1;
private String  Name;

public Table1() {
}
public Table1(int id,Date Data1, String Name) {
this.id = id;
this.Data1 = Data1;
this.Name = Name;
}
public int getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
public Date getData1() {
return Data1;
}
public void setData1(Date Data1) {
this.Data1 = Data1;
}
public String getName() {
return Name;
}
public void setName(String Name) {
this.Name = Name;
}
public class Table2 {
private int id;
private int Vid;
private Date Data1;
private String  Name;

public Table2() {
}
public Table1(int id, String Pole, String Name) {
this.id = id;
this.Pole = Pole;
this.Name = Name;
}
public int getId() {
return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}
public String getPole() {
return Pole;
}
public void setPole(String Pole) {
this.Data1 = Data1;
}
public String getName() {
return Name;
}
public void setName(String Name) {
this.Name = Name;
}

public String insert(String shema, String table, List records) throws Exception {

String query = "";

String result = "";

PreparedStatement stmt = null;
Registry.openConnection();
Connection conn = Registry.getConnection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
query ="INSERT into aa (а1..аn) vlues(?,?,?)";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

Вот тут и надр сделать setObject из records
stmt.setObject(1, Integer.parseInt(vid));
 stmt.setObject(2, genSQLDatePlus(date, 0));
 stmt.setObject(3, name);
int j = stmt.executeUpdate();
stmt.close();
conn.commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
conn.rollback();
throw new Exception(e);
} finally {
if (stmt != null) {
stmt.close();
}
Registry.closeConnection();
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется можно. Откройте для себя интерфейсы, без них в мире ООП совсем плохо. И посмотрите, что такое Service Layer... И обратите внимание на именование перменных. Перменные всегда именуются с маленькой буквы верблюжей нотацией. Константы именуются заглавными буквами через нижнее подчеркивание. Это кажется мелочью, но за это отрывают руки.
А теперь решение.
Создадим интерфейс, который будут имплементировать оба Ваших класса.

```
    public interface TableInterface {

        Date getData();

        int getId();

        String getName();

        void setData(Date data);

        void setId(int id);

        void setName(String name);

    }

import java.util.Date;

public class Table1 implements TableInterface {

    private int id;
    private Date data;
    private String name;

    public Table1() {}

    public Table1(int id, Date data, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void setData(Date data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

import java.util.Date;

public class Table2 implements TableInterface{

    private int id;
    private int vid;
    private Date data;
    private String name;

    public Table2() {}

    public Table2(int id, int vid, Date data, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.vid = vid;
    this.data = data;
    this.name = name;
}
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVid() {
        return vid;
    }

    public void setVid(int vid) {
        this.vid = vid;
    }

    public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Date data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Отлично! Теперь коллекция для записи экземпляров классов , будет выглядеть так

```
List <TableInterface> records = new ArrayList<>();
```

Поскольку коллекция типизирована Вашим интерфейсом, а не конкретным классом, она может хранить объекты всех классов, которые имплементируют этот интерфейс. Это значит что в эту коллекцию вы без проблем добавляете и єкземпляры класса Table1 и Table2.

После этого создаем универсальный метод (пусть будет сервис).

```
import java.util.List;

public class Service<T extends TableInterface> {
    public void ibsert(final List<T> tables) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            T t = tables.get(i);
            String name = t.getName();
            int vid = t.getId();
        }
    }
}
```

В метод insert этого сервиса вы передаете свою коллекцию с объектами двух Ваших классов. Вот и все.
Поскольку класс типизирован дженериком Т, который наследуется от Вашего интерфейса, то перемная типа Т в методе может использовать все методы интерфейса. При этом не имет никакого значения какой имено это объект - класса Table1 или Table2. 
Это и есть классический полиморфизм. 
Мало того, из сервисов обычно строится дерево с различным уровнем абстракций на каждом уровне, что позволяет, опускаясь ниже по дереву, конкретезировать вид объектов, пользуясь все более и более специфическими их методами (Service Layer).

Отличный и очень правильный вопрос! Удачи Вам.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91185/discussion-on-answer-by-------).